# How to read serial number of J-Link debug probe via cmd

Tags: cmd, segger-jlink

I am required to read the serial number of connected J-Link (I use J-Link Compact Plus from Segger) via the command line.

I am using tools from Segger such as JFlash.exe and JLink.exe

I managed to find a way to read a serial number via JLink.exe by executing the following command:

```
JLink.exe -CommanderScript -CommandFile GetSerial.jlink
```

Where GetSerial.jlink is a custom file that I have created and it looks like:

```
ShowEmuList
exit
```

The response is as following:
[image]

The above method seems to work fine but I am not convinced that this is the most optimal way.

**My questions:**

1. Is it possible to read the serial number using JFlash.exe instead of JLink.exe. Since I use JFlash.exe from flashing, I would prefer to rely on a single tool instead of 2.
2. If the answer to above is **no**. I would like to know if there is any way to optimise the JLink.exe command to read the device serial number. I do not fully understand why do I need to pass GetSerial.jlink as an argument to the command. I would much rather prefer something like:

```
Jlink.exe -ShowEmuList
```

But the above does not seem to work:
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I would help to know why you want to get the S/N of the J-Link.
Both applications are designed with the following workflow in mind:
Start -> Select J-Link (by User input or by command line argument; autoselects J-Link if only one is connected) -> use the application.

Comment: Hello. For my application, I have many J-Links connected and I need to know which device is connected to which J-Link. In order to determine this (without manually looking at the J-Link and reading serial number) , I need a command so that computer can do this for me. I ended up sticking with JLink.exe as I have initially posted because I didint manage to find a better way at a time

Comment: "and I need to know which device is connected to which J-Link. "
This is not possible, the J-Link software needs to know the device on order to make a proper connect. 
Or do you mean: You have a list of S/Ns -> Device name, and you want to have the s/n of the connected J-Link(s), so that you can pass the correct device name into the connect?

Sorry for the questions but I still dont understand the flow of events.

Answer (score 0):

1: I couldn't find anything in the JFlash reference.

To answer 2:
The command line options for JLinkEXE are not that good, unfortunately. If you just need the connected emulators printed, I would rather go for Nordic Semiconductors `nrfjprog`, part of the nRF Command Line tools found [here](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-command-line-tools/download).

Then you can simply do

```
# nrfjprog -i
960063027
960036138
960019988
821009140
```

It has a lot of other nice features as well but is mostly made for their nRF-chipsets though. If you are indeed using their chipset, this is a one-stop shop for everything you need.